# Applying more in depth selection to the :host CSS pseudo class

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors, web-component, pseudo-class

I am making a custom element and have been searching for a way of adding more specificity to the `:host` pseudo class which is associated with the shadow DOM. From my understanding it is used to select the actual custom element itself. For example, if I had an element called `my-elem` which had a shadow DOM attached the `:host` pseudo class would be equivalent to a class under `my-elem` in a global stylesheet.

From this I wanted to try and further specify the selector so that I could style the custom elements on their state, for example: `:host:not(.active)`. However, I cannot really find any reading on further specificity regarding the `:host` and using the aforementioned does not work.

I have also tried the traditional `:host.active` and even the cheeky `:host[active]` however none of them work.

So I wanted to ask if this is even possible. I have done some searching online but there doesn't really seem to be all that much online on the matter and I feel that it may not be possible so I will, possibly have to go a level down and apply the active class to the wrapper of the custom element upon state change.

I just wanted to do it this way as it allows me to programatically style the elements from their parent (I am apply the active/inactive styles to custom slides of a custom element form).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you try :host(.active)?

Comment: @Supersharp Thanks mate that did the trick!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- `:host(.active)` is for a Class selector notation:

  **`<my-element class="active" ></my-element>"`**

.

- `:host([active])` is for an Attribute selector notation:

  **`<my-element active="..." ></my-element>"`**

.

I presume you mean to use the **`:active` Pseudo-Class**, like `:hover`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes

**Correct syntax**:

```
:host(:active){
  color:yellow;
}
```

If you also have a `:hover` in your element:

```
:host(:hover){
  color:green;
}
```

you then need to force Specificity (https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) with:

```
:host(:active:active){
  color:yellow;
}
```

**:not notation is then:**

```
:host(:not(:active)){
  color:grey;
}
```

This *of course* has higher Specificity than `:hover`

So to make `:hover` work again, you need to increase Specificity:

```
:host(:hover:hover){
  color:green;
}
```

Comment: Thank you mate, that has done the trick. This went over my head as I thought that using the () was only to style the parent container of the actual element.

Comment: Can I write nested `&` inside? Like if it's hovered **and** has class `empty`? Something like `:host(:hover) { color: green;  &.empty { background-color: grey; } }` ?