# CSS selector `:host > some_child_element` doesn't take effect?

Tags: css, web-component, shadow-dom

I have this custom element:

```
<my-custom-form>
  #shadow-root
   <style>
     :host label {
        color: red;
     }
   </style>
   <div id="wrapper">
     <slot name="form-label"></slot>
     ...
   </div>
</my-custom-form>
```

Now I use it as follows:

```
<my-custom-form>
    <label slot="form-label">Some Label</label>
</my-custom-form>
```

I expected that the `label` should be styled as red color. But it isn't.
Isn't `<label>` element residing in the light DOM as a direct child of :host?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're having is issue in syntax,try doing:

- `:host( [label] ){ }`

here's another answer on SO that will clear your duobt!

- [Applying more in depth selection to the :host CSS pseudo class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59703607/applying-more-in-depth-selection-to-the-host-css-pseudo-class)

Documentation reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:host()

Comment: I believe there must be a typo. `:host( [label]) {}` selects a host element with `label` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Slotted content is **reflected** in shadowDOM, does not become part of shadowDOM.

So styling is done in lightDOM (with global CSS)

`:host()` only styles the out "skin" in lightDOM

Long detailed explanation: [::slotted CSS selector for nested children in shadowDOM slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626493/slotted-css-selector-for-nested-children-in-shadowdom-slot/61631668#61631668)